# jquery/javascript alert if all fields are not completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form which I'd like to alert people if ALL of the fields aren't completed. I am currently using a jquery validation script for the required fields, but I need it to also let people know that not all of the fields are filled out before saving (they're not required fields, but just to let them know that the form isn't finished).

The form fields are:

type, status, rating, cterms, companyid, company, name, surname, address, suburb, city, state, country, pcode, phone, email and comments

If someone could help me out with this, that'd be great, I dont mind if it's with jquery or javascript, just something that will alert that not all of the fields are completed and if they want to continue with the save or not.

Cheers

Leanne

EDIT:

Here's the form:

```
<form action="/index.php?option=com_database&view=add&Itemid=3&task=save" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong> </strong></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Active:</strong></td>
            <td><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="radio" name="published" id="published0" value="0" checked="checked" /></td>
                  <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="published0">No</label>
                  </td>
                  <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="radio" name="published" id="published1" value="1" /></td>
                  <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="published1">Yes</label></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Date:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="admintable"><input class="text_area" type="text" name="date" id="date" size="30" value="22/09/2009" disabled="disabled" style="width: 200px;" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Type:</strong></td>
            <td><select name="type" id="type" size="1" class="validate[required]" style="width: 205px;">
                <option value="">- Select Type -</option>
                <option value="1">Customer</option>
                <option value="2">Supplier</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="admintable">
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Status:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><select name="status" id="status" size="1" class="validate[required]" style="width: 205px;">
                <option value="">- Select Status -</option>
                <option value="1">Existing</option>
                <option value="2">Potential</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Rating:</strong></td>
            <td><select name="rating" id="rating" size="1" class="validate[required]" style="width: 205px;">
                <option value="">- Select Rating -</option>
                <option value="1">Principal</option>
                <option value="2">Secondary</option>
                <option value="3">Minor</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="admintable">
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Credit Terms:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><select name="cterms" id="cterms" size="1" class="validate[required]" style="width: 205px;">
                <option value="">- Select Credit Terms -</option>
                <option value="1">COD</option>
                <option value="2">30 Days</option>
                <option value="3">60 Days</option>
                <option value="4">90 Days</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Database:</strong></td>
            <td><select name="companyid" id="companyid" size="1" class="validate[required]" style="width: 205px;">
                <option value="">- Select Database -</option>
                <option value="2">Cody Opal</option>
                <option value="1">National Opal Collection</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Company:</strong></td>
            <td><input class="validate[required] text_area" type="text" name="company" id="company" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Address:</strong></td>
            <td><input class="validate[required] text_area" type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Address 2:</strong></td>
            <td><input class="text_area" type="text" name="address2" id="address2" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Suburb:</strong></td>
            <td><input class="validate[required] text_area" type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>City:</strong></td>
            <td><input class="validate[required] text_area" type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>State:</strong></td>
            <td><div id="entry_state1">
                <input class="validate[required] text_area" type="text" name="state" id="state" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" />
              </div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Postcode:</strong></td>
            <td><input class="validate[required] text_area" type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Country:</strong></td>
            <td><select name="country" id="country" onChange="javascript: loadstate1();" class="selectstate validate[required]">
                <option value="">- Select Country -</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Primary Contact Name:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="validate[required] text_area" type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Primary Contact Surname:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="text_area" type="text" name="surname" id="surname" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Primary Contact Position:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="text_area" type="text" name="position" id="position" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Primary Contact Email:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="validate[required,custom[email]] text_area" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Secondary Contact:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="text_area" type="text" name="contact" id="contact" size="30" value="" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Phone - Business:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="validate[required] text_area" name="country_code[]" type="text" id="country_code" value="+" size="2" maxlength="5" style="width: 33px;" />
              <input class="validate[required,custom[telephone]] text_area" type="text" name="phone_b" id="phone_b" size="22" value="" style="width: 160px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Phone - Direct:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="text_area" name="country_code[]" type="text" id="country_code" value="+" size="2" maxlength="5" style="width: 33px;" />
              <input class="validate[optional,custom[telephone]] text_area" type="text" name="phone_d" id="phone_d" size="22" value="" style="width: 160px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Phone - Mobile:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="text_area" name="country_code[]" type="text" id="country_code" value="+" size="2" maxlength="5" style="width: 33px;" />
              <input class="validate[optional,custom[telephone]] text_area" type="text" name="phone_m" id="phone_m" size="22" value="" style="width: 160px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Phone - Personal:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="text_area" name="country_code[]" type="text" id="country_code" value="+" size="2" maxlength="5" style="width: 33px;" />
              <input class="validate[optional,custom[telephone]] text_area" type="text" name="phone_p" id="phone_p" size="22" value="" style="width: 160px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Fax:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input class="text_area" name="country_code[]" type="text" id="country_code" value="+" size="2" maxlength="5" style="width: 33px;" />
              <input class="validate[optional,custom[telephone]] text_area" type="text" name="phone_f" id="phone_f" size="22" value="" style="width: 160px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Customer Comments:</strong></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">
          <tr>
            <td width="160" align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" class="key"><strong>Classifications: </strong></td>
            <td><div class="company_1">
                <table width="135" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="border: solid 1px #ff0000; margin-right: 10px; background-color: #ff0000; background-image: url(/templates/home/scripts/opacity.png);" class="classTables">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="background-color: #ff0000; background-image: none; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;"><strong>OTHER</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="classifications[70]" id="classifications[70]" value="70" class="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="classifications[70]">VIP Client</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="classifications[71]" id="classifications[71]" value="71" class="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="classifications[71]">Retailer</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="classifications[72]" id="classifications[72]" value="72" class="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="classifications[72]">Media</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="classifications[73]" id="classifications[73]" value="73" class="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="classifications[73]">Consultant</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="classifications[74]" id="classifications[74]" value="74" class="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="classifications[74]">Contractor</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="classifications[75]" id="classifications[75]" value="75" class="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="classifications[75]">Other</label></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add New Client" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick mock-up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var incomplete = $('form :input').filter(function() {
                             return $(this).val() == '';
                         });
        //if incomplete contains any elements, the form has not been filled 
        if(incomplete.length) {
            alert('please fill out the form');
            //to prevent submission of the form
            return false;
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: That would not target descendants, especially if the form fields are enclosed with divisions for stylistic purposes.  (meder I stole your comment :P)

Comment: @jnylen - That's true, I don't know what the form looks like, but I guess that could be rectified using ancestor-descendant, i.e. 'form input' instead of 'form > input'. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 3):

```
function checkEmpty() {
       var empty = false;
       $("input").each(function() {
           empty = ($(this).val() == "") ? true : empty;
       });
       if(empty) {
           var empty_ok = confirm("Are you Ok with leaving stuff empty?");
           return empty_ok;
       }
```

the confirm returns a true if they click `yes` and false if they click `no`. Return that to the main validator as the value to pass to the submit() event.

Comment: Better to use $(":input", myForm). That will handle other input tags (textareas, etc.) and multiple forms on a page. (Catching other input tags is probably more important, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each input element in a form:

```
$(':input', formName).each(function() {
    // Check for completion of each input type
})
```

Comment: That would not target descendants, especially if the form fields are enclosed with divisions for stylistic purposes.

Comment: You're looking at the modified version of the code after my comment. See the initial version.

Comment: Yep, I should have said that. This question was answered above with what looks to be a solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

( This is why I asked for the markup before blindly answering )

I don't think any of the solutions above account for the logic that only *one* of the checkboxes must actually be checked and you shouldn't just check if each of them has a value or they would all have one by default. Here's my version which relies on the `div` enclosing the checkboxes to have a class of 'checkboxgroup'.

Also, the elements that are not filled in are populated to the 'errorElements' array, which you can loop through and add any warning notifications.

```
$(function() {
$('#adminForm').submit( function ( event ) {
    var errorElements  = window.errorElements = [], valid = false;

    $(':input', this).not(':checkbox').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ( !val.length ) {
        valid = false;
        errorElements.push(this);
    }
    });

    $('.checkboxgroup', this).each(function() {
    var checkBoxes = $(':checkbox', this), oneChecked = false;
    checkBoxes.each(function() {
        if ( !oneChecked && !$(this).is(':checked') ) {
        valid = false;
        errorElements.push(this);
        } else {
        oneChecked = true;
        }
    });
    });

    if ( !errorElements.length ) {
    valid = true;
    }

    if ( !valid ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('please fill in all form fields.');
    } else {
    alert('congratulations');
    }

});
});
```

Checkbox Snippet:

```
  <div class="company_1 checkboxgroup">
                <table width="135" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="border: solid 1px #ff0000; margin-right: 10px; background-color: #ff0000; background-image: url(/templates/home/scripts/opacity.png);" class="classTables">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="background-color: #ff0000; background-image: none; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;"><strong>OTHER</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="classifications[70]" id="classifications[70]" value="70" class="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="classifications[70]">VIP Client</label></td>
```

If you have multiple checkbox groups just have an element enclosing them with the .checkboxgroup class.