# Show message instead of alert

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, alert

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457713/jquery-javascript-alert-if-all-fields-are-not-completed) amazing javascript to check if all my fields are filled in, but instead of a alert box I want to show a message on my page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function() {
    var incomplete = $('form :input').filter(function() {
                         return $(this).val() == '';
                     });
    //if incomplete contains any elements, the form has not been filled 
    if(incomplete.length) {
        alert('Vul alle velden in en probeer het nog eens');
        //to prevent submission of the form
        return false;
    }
 });
 });
```

I tried to play with echo messages but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can styling your own popup. Or use some plugins.

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-popup-window-tutorial-plugins.html

Or you can create some element on the page, that will showing the error messages. Write some styles and make it look awesome !

```
<div class="error-messages" style="display:none;"></div>
```

After the form sending, and checking errors, write this.

```
$(".error-messages").text("Some error").fadeIn();
```

Or you can make it empty and hide it, after a seconds or after user focus.

```
$(".error-messages").empty().fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can insert a hidden div above your form, and show it instead of the alert

```
<div class="form-errors"></div>

$(".form-errors").text("The form is not complete").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with the DOM, e.g. something like this:

```
$('#errorDiv').append("Error on element" + elementName);
```

where you have to predefine an error Div ('#errorDiv').

Answer (score 0):

Add hidden div aligned with your elements and show the message on hidden div's instead of alert box.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you have to work with the DOM. If you have the time, however, I would advice you advice you to not simply copy/paste a line of jquery but to look into what the DOM actually is and how to manipulate it in pure javascript. Here's a starting point:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
<header>
<h2>My Form</h2>
<p>This is my form. Fill it out</p>
 </header>

 <!-- To make a responsive form each element of the form should be in a separate div.!-->
<div id="responsive">

   <div>
  <label for="name"> Enter your information below </label>
             <div><Input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Sajid Mehmood"           width="100px;" autofocus></div>
       </div>


    </div>
   !-->




   <div>
   <div>
    <Input type="submit" value="Click me" onclick="msg()" >
   </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use for a form, maybe it can help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){

        $('#form').validate({
             ignore: ".ignore",
                rules:{
                    "name":{
                        required:true,
                        maxlength:40
                    },

                    "phone":{
                        required:true,                            
                    },

                    "email":{
                        required:true,
                        email:true,
                        maxlength:100
                    },

                    hiddenRecaptcha: {
                        required: function () {
                            if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }}},

                    "message":{
                        required:true
                    }},

                messages:{
                    "name":{
                        required:"Please tell us your name"
                    },
                    "phone":{
                        required:"Please tell us your phone number"
                    },

                    "email":{
                        required:"How can we send you information? We promise, we will never give away your email!",
                        email:"Please enter a valid email address"
                    },

                    "hiddenRecaptcha":{
                        required:"Please check the box to show us you are human"  
                    },

                    "message":{
                        required:"Please tell us what we can tell you about this vessel"
                    }},

                submitHandler: function(form){
                  $(form).ajaxSubmit({
    target: '#preview', 
    success: function() { 
    $('#formbox').slideUp('fast'); 
    } 
});     
                }
        })          
    });
    </script>


<div id="preview"></div>
        <div id="formbox">  
        <div>    
        <p class="contactform">Contact Form:</p>  
            <form name="form" id="form" action="http://www.yourdomaingoeshere.com/submit.php" method="post">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your site key goes here" style="padding-bottom: 20px!important;"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
                <ul id="ngothastyle3" class="mylist">                       
                    <li class="mylist">                        
                        <input type="text" placeholder="your name" name="name" class=""  />
                    </li>
                    <li class="mylist">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="phone number" name="phone" class="" />
                    </li>
                     <li class="mylist">                        
                        <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" class="" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="mylist">                        
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="comments" rows="5" cols="45" class=""></textarea>
                    </li>

        </div> 


        <div style="float: right;">
                    <li class="mylist" style="list-style: none;">                        
                        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
                    </li>
        </div>            
                </ul>
            </form>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.